# the SQL command Line of ORACLE is not creating a table, it keeps asking me for more lines of code

Tags: sql, oracle, command-line, oracle11g

i wrote a simple code of creating a small table , but it looks like the SQL RUN COMMAND LINE don't understand that its he end of the CREATE TABLE , it demand more instruction !
i've tried many tables and also tried drop and nothing works!
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to add a ';' at the end of the SQL statement ?

[SQL*Plus Basics doc. section says](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/SQL-Plus-basics.html#GUID-33A1B51B-2DF4-41CE-9656-D35400201208)

> You can end a SQL command in one of three ways:
>
> ```
> with a semicolon (;)
>
> with a slash (/) on a line by itself
>
> with a blank line
> ```
>
> A semicolon (;) tells SQL*Plus that you want to run the command. Type
>   the semicolon at the end of the last line of the command, as shown in
>   Example 4-3, and press Return or click Execute. SQL*Plus processes the
>   command and also stores the command in the SQL buffer. See The SQL
>   Buffer for details. If you mistakenly press Return before typing the
>   semicolon, SQL*Plus prompts you with a line number for the next line
>   of your command. Type the semicolon and press Return again or click
>   Execute to run the command.
>
> A slash (/) on a line by itself also tells SQL*Plus that you wish to
>   run the command. Press Return at the end of the last line of the
>   command. SQL*Plus prompts you with another line number. Type a slash
>   and press Return again or click Execute. SQL*Plus executes the command
>   and stores it in the buffer.
>
> A blank line in a SQL statement or script tells SQL*Plus that you have
>   finished entering the command, but do not want to run it yet. Press
>   Return at the end of the last line of the command. SQL*Plus prompts
>   you with another line number.